# Post Update in Facebook in Android failed

Tags: android, facebook

Hy!

I am using easyfacebookandroidsdk( http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/guide.asp) for posting a status in facebook.

I made a FB App and entered my Android Key Hash.

My Code:

```
public class FBConnect extends GDActivity implements LoginListener{

     private FBLoginManager fbManager;

     //replace it with your own Facebook App ID
     String title = "Herr der Ringe";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //setContentView(R.layout.main);
      setTitle("Facebook");
      //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      //title=extras.getString("title");
    shareFacebook();
     }
     public void shareFacebook() {

            //change the permissions according to the function you want to use 
                    String permissions[] = { "read_stream","publish_actions" };

                    //change the parameters with those of your application
                    fbManager = new FBLoginManager(this, R.layout.main,
                                    "xxxxxxxxx", permissions);

                    if (fbManager.existsSavedFacebook()) {
                            fbManager.loadFacebook();
                    } else {

                            fbManager.login();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    fbManager.loginSuccess(data);
            }

            public void loginFail() {
                    fbManager.displayToast("Login failed!");

            }

            public void logoutSuccess() {
                    fbManager.displayToast("Logout success!");
            }

            public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

                    //library use example
                    RestApi rest = new RestApi(facebook);
                    try {

                        rest.setStatus("I just watched "+title+"  and marked it in TVBrain for Android");
                        Log.e("XXX FB","OK");
                    } catch (EasyFacebookError e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("XXX FB","ERROR");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



            }



}
```

Error:

```
03-25 23:36:42.358: W/Bundle(931): Key status expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:157)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.365: W/Bundle(931): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:157)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.369: W/Bundle(931): Key method expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:157)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:42.373: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.377: W/Bundle(931): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:157)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:42.381: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.740: W/Bundle(931): Key status expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:65)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:184)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.744: W/Bundle(931): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:65)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:184)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.748: W/Bundle(931): Key method expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:65)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:184)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.752: W/Bundle(931): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1363)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:65)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.util.Util.openUrl(Util.java:184)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatusCall(RestApi.java:119)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.apicall.RestApi.setStatus(RestApi.java:100)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.korn.tvbrain.overview.FBConnect.loginSuccess(FBConnect.java:72)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.LoggedInThread$1.handleMessage(LoggedInThread.java:33)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-25 23:36:43.756: W/Bundle(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

No update appears in facebook.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, the stack trace says that you're trying to cast a String to a byte[], which sounds like it should work but won't.

Hard to say where it's happening, because you're using a Facebook API that I'm not familiar with.

Follow the stack trace until you find a call that's in your code. Then start from there.

I'd say that it's at
Util.openUrl() in the Facebook API. Does this expect a byte[], and you're passing a String?

Comment: That same flaw, or a similar one, exists in the official facebook API as well, in a few places.  Even though easyfacebookandroid isn't the official FB SDK for Android it might be worthwhile to look at some posts on StackOverflow that do deal with Facebook's official SDK as the logical errors may be similar.